# Why is my redis docker listening on port 6379 and not port 6380?

Tags: docker, redis, docker-compose

I have set my docker compose to use a redis conf file which specifies the port as `6380` but it keeps listening to 6379. What am i doing wrong?

*Note: the `redis.conf` is in the same directory I'm running `docker-compose up -d` from*

**redis.conf**

```
port 6380
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
redis1:
  image: redis:3.2-alpine
  ports:
    - 6380:6380
  volumes:
    - ./redis.conf:/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
  command: redis-server /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
  networks:
    foonet:
      ipv4_address: 172.22.1.10
```

Comment: Are you sure that config was overriden? `docker exec -it container_name bash` into it and check.

Comment: @michalk Using bash and looking at the file, it's there and correct. But when I ask Sentinel, it says it's port 6379

Comment: I have just used your compose and I got the correct port : `The server is now ready to accept connections on port 6380` form redis container. So you are actually running several services with redis master-sentinel configuration? Are you using this compose for docker swarm?

Comment: How do you exactly ask the sentinel for port?

Comment: @michalk I found out the reason. I needed to also change my sentinel config to get a conf file that points it to the new port for redis